# How to sync Notes over iCloud?

Tags: icloud, notes.app, mobile-mail

I am having trouble getting my iPhone to see the notes that are stored on my iCloud account.

So, my computer is running OS X Lion, on System Preferences > iCloud the "Mail and Notes" option is checked, and using the Mail app I can see my notes under the "iCloud" folder. However, these notes do not appear when I open the Notes app on the iPhone.

Now on my phone (3GS running iOS 5.1) I have on Settings > iCloud all options activated (including Mail and Notes). If I go to "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" I also see there my iCloud account registered, and Notes is as well selected. In Settings > Notes I only get an option to select the Font.

What am I missing? What should I do so that the Notes app on the iPhone is able to show my iCloud notes?

*Update:* Probably related to this issue, I've noticed that even if the phone is set to sync with iCloud mail as well, it only "sees" my gmail and work accounts/inboxes, and *not* the iCloud inbox. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I managed to get it working following the advise of another [discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3383527?start=0&tstart=0) on the Apple forums; namely:

> Same thing happend to me on my 3gs, i went to Settings...iCloud...Delete Account
>   then signed in again to add it. The iCloud inbox was displayed afterwards.

This also fixed the problem of notes, which now show up properly on the notes application.

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone, when you are showing the list of notes: It says "Accounts" on the top left. Tap an see what you have in the iCloud account and what you have in local accounts.

If you want to avoid deleting the iCloud account, you can copy the contents one by one from the local (on my iPhone) to the iCloud one.

On the other hand, if you are willing to delete an reactivate the iCloud account, make sure to merge the local and the iCloud contents.

For me, it was just one file that really mattered, so I did the copy paste described above.d

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your iCloud documents (without deleting them nor losing data, I just did it).

To do so, log in into http://www.icloud.com using your Apple ID
Go to the upper left button (the one with your name) and choose Account Settings
Click on Reset documents data... button

Restart your devices.

Re-configure your iCloud preferences if they were not OK

That should do the trick

See also: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5824